# Swap image src with jQuery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preloading, image-preloader

I have an `<img src="..." />` tag with a default `src` set. I'd like to have jQuery make an ajax request to get another image and when this new image is fully loaded, set the src of the `<img ... />` tag so there's no flicker. I'd prefer not to do any of the preloaders like `new Image().src="foo"` etc. I'd really like the iamges to load on an ajax request. Any ideas?

Comment: You could swap the ```<img>``` element altogether instead of changing the ```src``` attr. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/asychronously-load-images-with-jquery

Answer (score -1):

You cannot load "a part" of a image onto the webpage so you cannot load it incrementally.

The image can be loaded by using a CSS class point to an image or using Image object of Javascript.

Since CSS cannot notify the page whether the image fully load so the approach new Images().src = "foo" is the best it can do.

Attach an event to it and "decorate" it to reduce flicker with FX effect: fade in, ....