# find the dimensions of a dynamically loaded but DOM-appended image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, image, dimensions

I'm loading the source of an image dynamically using ajax, where `s` is this source. I create an image element in the DOM, assign it this source once it's loaded, and then append it to a `div` called `imgwrapper`. Then I try to get the image's dimensions, but it doesn't work. I'm aware you can't get the dimensions of an image that's dynamically loaded, but not even after being appended to the DOM?

My code is as below:

```
//use ajax to get value of s (the image source)
img = document.createElement("img"); 
img.src = s; 
$('#imgwrapper').appendChild(img); 
console.log($('#imgwrapper').find('img').width());
```

this returns 0, instead of giving me the image's width.

Comment: Are you sure it's in the DOM? There's no `$.appendChild()`, that should be [`$.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). On another note, you don't need to reselect the element after it's appended, you can just wrap `img` in a jQuery object: `$(img).width()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait till the image has finished loading

```
//use ajax to get value of s (the image source)
img = document.createElement("img"); 
img.onload = function() {
    console.log($('#imgwrapper').find('img').width());
};
img.src = s; 

$('#imgwrapper').append(img);
```

**Edit**
As @MattiasBuelens mentioned. There is no `.appendChild()` for a jQuery object. That should be `.append()` instead

Comment: Another optimization: use `$(img)` in the handler instead of reselecting.

Comment: If you really want to, you could go completely jQuery on this and use `$(img).on('load', function() { ... });` to bind the load handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
img = document.createElement("img"); 
img.src = "http://placehold.it/350x150"; 
$('#imgwrapper').append(img); 
console.log($('#imgwrapper').find('img').width());
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/adajuh/1/

Comment: you need to use append instate of appendChild

Comment: anyway it is answered above from @Andreas

Comment: This doesn't work, it still gives `0` on the first load. When you load it the second time, it works since the image is already in the cache - but that's cheating. Try it yourself: press Ctrl+F5 and check the console.