# Cross call working with Post but failing with pre-flight

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, preflight

I have to make web service call from my websites to thirdparty domain/server.
While I am making this call using jQuery Ajax by Post method with content-type:text/plain and it is working fine.

But while I am changing it to content-type: text/xml it is throwing:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Even it set on thirdparty server to allow access to our website. And we are getting this header while making call with content-type:text/plain.

We have also added following on Thirdparty server.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : Get , Post , Options ,PUT

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,origin, content-type, accept
```

Please let me know what could be the reason that pre-flight request is not getting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in response?

Comment: I have changed Soap service to Rest service and now Options calls are having all required control-access-* header. I don't know what was wrong with Soap Call.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your script is working for text/plain is because it is a simple request. If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work), you can see that your text/plain request fits the requirements for a simple request. However, when you change the content-type to text/xml it changes it to a "non-simple" request.

In order to make your "non-simple" request work, you will need to look at how to make a pre-flight request. [This website](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server) explains how you can do that under "Handling a not-so-simple request".

## Update

Just a Note:
The `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` is cast sensitive (all uppercase), and you do not need to list any methods used for a simple request (GET, HEAD, POST). - [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Accept
```

> Firefox doesn't include an Origin header on same-origin requests. But Chrome and Safari include an Origin header on same-origin POST/PUT/DELETE requests (same-origin GET requests will not have an Origin header).

Is there a possibility that the origin is the same?

Could there be an issue with your [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228839/all-of-my-browsers-are-not-sending-the-origin-header)?

Make sure you have these [settings](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for your jquery ajax call:

```
crossDomain: true // Will force a cross domain request
cache: false
```

Comment: Yes I know it is simple request and other one is "not so simple request". The question is that in one request I am getting all access-control-* header but in Option I am not getting these headers. so my  "not so simple request" is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `content-type:text/plain` and `content-type: text/xml` is: "text/xml" requires "preflight" but "text/plain" does not.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests):

> In particular, a request is preflighted if:
>
> It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used
>   to send request data with a Content-Type other than
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
>   e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using
>   application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.

Some potential reasons those can cause the fail of a preflight request:

1. CORS is not enabled by server. Search how to enable CORS for your server technology.
2. Server does not consume a request other than "text/plain". For example; Spring has a [consume option](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--) that defines which content-type is acceptable.
3. There is an "Authorization" header in your post. If you are sending requests with credentials, you should add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header also. Again from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).