# Is there a more reliable way to display images on a webpage when loaded from the database?

Tags: asp.net

I have a system where you can view photos as an extra detail to a record. Let's say it is a photo of an employee's cat.
These photos are stored in our database.

Currently when someone wishes to view the kitty. We render an `img` tag like so.

```
<a href="#" onclick="RenderTag('20');return false;">View Kitty</a>
<div id="imageDiv"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function RenderTag(id){
    $('#imageDiv').html('<img src="http://localhost/GetKitty.aspx?ID=' + id + '" />');
}
</script>
```

And the GetKitty.aspx works like so

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;FileName=kitty.bmp");
    Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
    Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Bitmap kitty = GetKittyBitmap(Request.QueryString("ID"));
    kitty.Save(Response.OutputStream, kitty.RawFormat);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    kitty.Dispose();
}
```

After clicking the anchor link the page is like so.
[image]

The problem is that sometimes the kitty doesn't show up on our mobile devices and my users get frustrated and call someone who is in the office to take a picture of the kitty with their mobile phone and email the kitty picture to them.

The demand for emailed pictures of kitties is so great that they are now asking for email functionality of sending kitty pictures be built into the system.

Building that functionality could be avoided if the darn pictures of the kitties would just render all the time as expected.

Is there a more reliable method of displaying images that are stored in the database?

Comment: Are you able to reliably reproduce the problem?  When the kitty "doesn't show up" what is the physical problem preventing it from happening?

Comment: @David he probably needs are assistance with exactly that...reproducing the problem

Comment: It is completely random, I can see the kitty being sent to the client from the server and see the client receive the picture then the client just sits there with no kitty picture and no red X picture either. I'm thinking that perhaps something is getting confused between the aspx request and the image response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've discovered a reliable way to get the kitties to always render!

It appears that if I add a `Content-Length` header it resolves the issue.

I implement it like so.

```
using (MemoryStream inputMS = NewMemoryStream(kittyBytes))
using (Bitmap kittyBitmap = new Bitmap(inputMS))
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    //Some logic goes here determining the image type of the kitty
    //We send low rez jpgs at certain times
    string kittyFileSuffix = ".bmp";
    string kittyContentType = "image/bmp";

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;FileName=Kitty" + kittyFileType);
    Response.ContentType = kittyContentType;
    using (Image smallKitty = ResizeKitty(kittyBitmap))
    {
        long quality = 40;
        Imaging.EncoderParameters ep = new Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
        ep.Param[0] = new Imaging.EncoderParameter(Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
        using (MemoryStream outputMS = new MemoryStream())
        {
            smallKitty.Save(outputMS, GetImageCodecInfo(kittyContentType), ep);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", outputMS.Length);
            outputMS.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close():
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery .load function to supply error-handling features (and probably restarting getting an image) as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/can-jquery-ajax-load-image) SO post.

Answer (score 0):

While I see no problem with this approach, you should implement this as an HttpHandler(.ashx)

Kitty would get out of your server faster if it didn't have to run though the entire Page lifecycle followed by an aspx page.

Since you are sending this picture over the web, consider using a compressed format like jpg or png. Bitmaps are large. Quicker you send kitty out the better.

Load test your application, downloading several times from several clients and saving the file. IIS sometimes hit a limit with the number of simultaneous requests it can process.

If you have a page with several such kitty images on a page, it is that many requests to asp.net. The default number of threads is only 25 on asp.net 2.0.