# Page loading issue with wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

My system  is in wordpress -php.

Home page load so many images from third party server(itunes store) . It's take to long time in page load.

Can anybody guide me how to resolve this problem Like we first load  all the contents and then after load all images.

At least customers can see the page with content.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed a Cache plugin on your wordpress like W3 Total Cache?
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/

If not, you can try to use Ajax to load your images from third party, then your content will be shown directly and your third party images will load without slowing the loading of the content.

Check this : http://api.jquery.com/load/ (Don't forget to use Jquery.noconflict() )

Or you can try this plugin : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/

Comment: pls see this link :http://top10appstoday.com/ .    I add w3-total-cache plugin but still same issue. It takes very long when someone open site first time.

Comment: how to call ajax for all images at a time ?

Comment: See this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/can-jquery-ajax-load-image

Answer (score 0):

Honestly when you are depending on third party for piece of content page loading time will be always a issue. I will recommend you to use [breeze cache plugin](https://www.cloudways.com/en/free-wordpress-cache-plugin-breeze.php) as well as multi regional WordPress Hosting which eventually help your website load basics elements from cache. Secondly closely watch out for rending issue because many WordPress website delay are just because of few lines of code mysteriously typed which can be tested on [pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com) or page insight. All the best mate. Cheers