# Loading images with ajax (in rails)

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can jquery .ajax load image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/can-jquery-ajax-load-image)

Is there a way to either:

load images via an ajax request

or

put a loading icon instead of where the image should be (or some other placeholder) until the image is fully loaded?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far? Run a Google search, try something, then ask a specific question about what you're struggling with.

Comment: I've searched for an answer yet couldn't find anything of that sort. That's why I've asked here. your answer is not constructive nor helpful.

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4285068/344923