# Can Dojo .ajax load image?

Tags: ajax, image, dojo

There is a similar question for Jquery here:
[Asynchronously load images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/can-jquery-ajax-load-image)

The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4285068/150050) is quite clever and works well (for Jquery):

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://somedomain.com/image.jpg')
  .load(function() {
      if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
          alert('broken image!');
      } else {
          $("#something").append(img);
      }
  });
```

My question is, what would be the canonical equivlent to this in Dojo (including the error handling)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "dojox.form.Uploader" to ajax upload image.

Dojo code:-

```
require(['dojox/form/Uploader'],function(Uploader)
{
    var uploader = new Uploader(
    {
       uploadOnSelect:true,   //Upload file on file select
       url:'UploadFile.php',  //Path of your server file
       label:'',              //Label of uploader
       multiple:true          //Select multiple file to upload
    },'uploader');
    uploader.startup();
});
```

HTML code:-

```
<div id="uploader"></div>
```

"dojox.form.Uploader" provide various properties, method and event which is help to upload file.
I hope this will help you.