# JS/JQuery Retry Img Load After 1 Second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a request calling up a bunch of images like so:

```
<a href='www.domain1.com'><img src='../image/img1.png' onerror='imgError(this);'/></a>
<a href='www.domain2.com'><img src='../image/img2.png' onerror='imgError(this);'/></a>
```

The problem is when the call is made some of the images (~20%) are not ready yet. They need another second.

So in js or jquery what I would like to do is on error get the images that failed, wait 1 second, then try to load those failed images again. If they fail on the 2nd try -- oh well, Im okay with that. But Im not doing this correctly... Should I not be calling a timeout inside of another method in js?

```
function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = image;

    setTimeout(function () {
        return true;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Why in the world do you want to do this?  Besides the issues in your implementation, I suspect that setting `img.src` to what it's already set doesn't do anything.

Comment: Haha. Well. Im actually using imagemajick in between the initial ajax and loading the images. What is the better practice for something like this? Thank u btw 4 the comment...

Comment: Check out this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/can-jquery-ajax-load-image

Comment: FYI, @SamuelO'Malley, though the OP mentions AJAX, I believe there is no AJAX here, or needing to be here.

Comment: Thanks @PaulDraper, I wasn't sure if he actually wanted to use AJAX or not.

Comment: My apologies for lack of clarity. Thank you both for your help and edits.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a cache breaker.

```
function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = null;
    setTimeout(function (){
        image.src += '?' + +new Date;
     }, 1000);
}
```

(This assumes your image URL doesn't already have a query string, per the example. If it does, a little more work is obviously required.)