# Receiving binary data using enyo.Ajax

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, enyo

I am trying to download a image, which is nothing but a chunk of binary data, using imagelink. For downloading i am using enyo.Ajax module. It is giving back an warning : "**Ajax request set to handleAs JSON but data was not in JSON format** " .
following is what i have implemented till now.

```
enyo.kind({
name:"enyo.sample.ajaxapp",
components:[
    {kind:"onyx.Input",name:"urlinput", placeholder:"Input URL",classes:"input"},
    {kind:"onyx.Button",name:"download",ontap:"fetch",classes:"button",content:"Fetch"},
    {kind:"enyo.Control",name:"image",tag:"img",classes:"image"}
],
fetch:function(inSender,inEvent){
    var ajax= new enyo.Ajax({
        url:this.$.urlinput.getValue(),
        handleAs:'blob'
    });
    ajax.go();
    ajax.responseType='blob';
    ajax.response(this,"processResponse");
    ajax.error(this,"errorResponse");
},
processResponse:function(inSender,inResponse){
    var img=this.$.image;
    var blob=inResponse;
    //var data=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    img.setSrc(blob);
},
errorResponse:function(inSender,inResponse){
    console.log("error occured");
}
});
```

I wants to know whether is it not possible to get data apart from json/text/xml? If not, then how can i modify my code to get it downloaded. By default all the data received as JSON, so i am setting handleAs to bolb while creating ajax object. Do i need to change contentType or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Ajax is the best way to request image data.  You have (at least) two solutions:

1. Set the `src` attribute on an `<img>` tag and use `onload` to know
   when the resource was downloaded.
2. Base 64 encode the image from the
   server and set the `src` as the encoded data plus the appropriate
   header info.

See this question for more details:  [Asynchronously load images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/can-jquery-ajax-load-image)