# Redirect or show an error message on error when rendering img html component

Tags: javascript, html

I get back a simple `html` page from a request to my homemade server:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Server Sample</title>
  </head>
  <img src="/stream.jpeg">
</html>
```

To render the image in `img` in the page, a second request is made to the server, under the path /stream.jpeg to get the actual image data. However, if this request fails for some reasons, I would like to show  the user an error page, or a message somehow. Redirecting or producing an html error page from the context of the failing request does not seem to work, probably because the initial page expects an image. In this case the page shows "an empty" img tag instead of the wanted error.

What is the most portable way to solve this problem? I prefer using html solutions, if possible, but also javascript is allowed.

Note that the server I wrote is very very simple and generates very simple pages dynamically, it does not the sort of extension which a complex server can offer.

Comment: You can see the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/can-jquery-ajax-load-image

Comment: but does that need jquery and these sort of stuff? Mine is a very simple, homemade http server , I can generate simple pages dinamically , don't want/cannot rely on complex things...

Comment: jQuery is very simple - it's just a js library that makes using js much easier, for example it makes doing an ajax call (which you need to do to check if the image url works or not) a lot simpler

Comment: The easy way is to use jQuery's ajax or load method. But if you in some reasons don't want to load the whole library just for one method, you can use native XMLHTTPRequest to get image data and do whatever you want with this. Here is doc: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="stream.jpeg" onerror="errorFunction();">
```

But `onerror` attribute is included in HTML5. So that will fail in older HTML.

JavaScript:

```
function errorFunction() {
  // Here you implement what's happening if the image failed to load.
  // For example:
  window.location.assign('http://my-site/error-page.html');
  // or
  console.log('Sorry, but image cannot be loaded right now.');
}
```

This function must be defined before `<img>` tag. Otherwise if image failed to load before the function is defined, HTML will not found this function and you will get an reference error.

Comment: HTML5 is fine, but what should errorFunction(); be? can you make an example in which errorFunction() would generate an error message?

Comment: Would it be possible to redirect by specifying a relative address, without knowing the address of the website, but taking it from the current URL in the address bar?

Comment: window.location.href contains current href (or path). You can try `window.location.assing(window.location.href + 'inner-page.html')`
window.location.origin contains the first part of the site for example: if you are at `http://google.com/search?q=something`... window.location.origin will return only `http://google.com`

Comment: Typo on window.location.assign