# PHP-Captcha-Script in Combination with jQuery-Load works in Webkit-Browsers only

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables

I've a simple PHP script (create.php) which outputs a Captcha-Image using an existing PNG-Image:

```
<?php
session_start();
$myimg = ImageCreateFromPNG("foobar.png");
$captcha = rand(1000,9999);
$_SESSION["captcha"] = $captcha;
$font = "path/to/font";
$fontsize = 15;
$txtcolor = ImageColorAllocate($myimg, 0,0,0);
$angle = 0;
$coordx = 10;
$coordy = 20;
imagettftext($myimg,$fontsize,$angle,$coordx,$coordy,$color,$font,$captcha);
imagepng($myimg);
imagedestroy($myimg);
?>
```

I'm calling this script like this (output.php):

```
<div id="refresh">
<img src="create.php" alt="foo" />
</div>
<span id="trigger-refresh">reload</span>
<script>
$('#trigger-refresh').click(function() {
  $('#refresh').load("refresh.php");
});
</script>
```

The file refresh.php just looks like this:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="create.php" alt="foo" />';
?>
```

When I call the refresh.php in browser, the Captcha-Image is shown correctly - everthing is fine. But after triggering the Jquery-Function in output.html the image/session does not reload. It's just working in Webkit-Browsers, e.g. Chrome. First I thought that the problem can be found in the browser-chache. So I cleared up cache - without any success.
Firebug shows that "refresh.php" is load but not the "create.php".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe putting the contents of "refresh.php" in your `#refresh` div is not enough to reload the contents of "create.php" in every browser (e.g. some browsers must just load "refresh.php" and leave "create.php" as-is as it was already loaded)

I would rather recommend you to create an `img` tag within your jQuery script, load its contents with the contents of "create.php" and then show that new `img` tag.

Example code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4285068/4475293

```
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'create.php')
    .load(function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            //error
        } else {
            //replace your img tag with the new one
        }
    });
```