# How to delay the display of the background image in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fiddle

Here's my [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2wx9rt7t/3/)

I just want the " `background-image:` " in the css to load fully and display after 3 seconds with a quick fade in effect, until then the entire div must be in black color.

How it is possible in `css` or `javascript`.

```css
.initials {
    position:absolute;
    background:black;
    background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif");
    color:white;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:60px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size:17px;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="initials">A</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the [CSS3 transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) otherwise you might considering javascript (jQuery) for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With some minor changes, I might have achieved what you want with only CSS3.
Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w11r4o3u/

CSS:

```
.initials {
    position:relative;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:60px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size:17px;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.initials .text {
    position: relative;
}

@-webkit-keyframes test {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.initials:before{
  content: "";
  background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif");
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: test;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="initials"><div class="text">A</div></div>
```

**Edited**:

Now the animation starts after 3 seconds and takes .3s to complete. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w11r4o3u/1/

- To adjust the "velocity" that fadeIn occurs, edit `-webkit-animation-duration: .3s;`
- If you want to adjust the animation "delay" to start, edit `-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;`

Comment: mind that OP is asking for a quick fadeIn after 3 seconds, not a 3 seconds fade in, might need to edit your answer accordingly

Comment: Already made the edit, now I also explained which properties control "velocity" and "delay" for the animation.

Comment: how do i load the image fully before displaying it, so that there is no image buffer after the fade-in effect ?

Comment: The image is already loaded, even if it's not displayed because of opacity. Check in your **Chrome Dev Tools**, in the **Network** tab.

Answer (score 5):

Like this perhaps...the fade in is tricky though - AFAIK you can't fade the background-image property

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.initials').css('background-image', 'url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif")');
}, 3000)
```

Another option is to split the HTML into 3 section, letters with highest z-index, then black layer over the stars layer...then fade out the black layer

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to have a separate class and assign that css to that class. Chech this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96otfvct/)

First you setup a method in document.ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       var changeClass = function() {
             $(".initials").addClass("with-image");
       }
       setTimeout(changeClass, 3000);
});
```

Then in your css you change initials to:

```
 .initials {
     position:absolute;
     background:black;
     background-COLOR: black; 
 ...
```

And add:

```
 .with-image {
       background-color:none !important;
       background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you see it now?

Comment: how do i make the image load fully before it is displayed?

Comment: my website contains a lot of images and this image loads along with all the others making it load halfway after the fade effect.

Comment: for the people having high speed connection it will will be smooth whereas for the people with moderate connection the gif image is loaded frame by frame..

Comment: When you declare background-image in your stylesheet, the image will be downloaded straight away when the browser is parsing your stylesheet regardless of what you call that class in the document or you do not

Answer (score 3):

You can create an absolute positioned div with the background image property and then use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to add an animation without having to create the keyframes yourself

http://jsfiddle.net/n9wd4ver/5/

```
.initials {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.initials.initials-text {
  padding:20px 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.initials.initials-background {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif");
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.initials-container {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    position:relative;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    width:60px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:17px;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="initials-container">
    <div class="initials initials-background animated fadeIn"></div>
    <div class="initials initials-text">A</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** OP asked in a comment how to check if the image has been loaded. I'm assuming you don't want to use jQuery, so you can use a library called [imagesLoaded](http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded) (which works both with and without jQuery) and check for image being loaded this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/n9wd4ver/7/

CSS

```
.initials {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.initials.initials-text {
  padding:20px 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#initials-background {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif");
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

#initials-background.animated {
  opacity: 1;
}



.initials-container {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    width:60px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:17px;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="initials-container">
<div id="initials-background" class="initials fadeIn">

</div>
<div class="initials initials-text">
A
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
imagesLoaded( '#initials-background', { background: true }, function() {
    console.log("image loaded");
  var d=document.getElementById("initials-background");
  d.className=d.className +" animated";
});
```

Comment: how do i make the image load fully before it is displayed ?

Comment: I have added at the end of my answer a way to check if an image has been loaded before starting the animation

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution, background image will appear after few seconds.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wx9rt7t/14/)**

Html

```
<div class="initials">A</div>
```

Css

```
.initials {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    color:white;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:60px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size:17px;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.initials').css('background-image', 'url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif")');
}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: The .fadeIn() applies to the DOM element you selected, not to the property you changed via .css(); The background-image is just changing instantly without proper fade.

Comment: how do i make the image load fully before it is displayed ?

Answer (score 2):

JQuery

```
 $('.initials').css('background-image','url(http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif)');
 $('.initials').fadeIn(3000);
```

Comment: This fades it all in - not what the OP wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/2wx9rt7t/16/)

Note: *You can test it by replacing url to and HD image url.*

```js
function loadImage() {
  var url = 'http://www.webgranth.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Ceric6.gif';
  var img = $("<img />").attr('src', url)
    .on('load', function() {
      $(".test").append(img).fadeIn(400);
    });
}

(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".bgImage").fadeIn(400);
  }, 3000);

  loadImage()
})()
```

```css
.content {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center
}
.initials {
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.bgImage {
  background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif");
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

.test {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="initials">
  <div class="bgImage"></div>
  <div class="content">A</div>
</div>

<div class="test"></div>
```

[Reference - Asychronously load images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/asychronously-load-images-with-jquery).

Comment: how do i make the image load fully before it is displayed ?

Comment: The ideal way would be using `Promise`.On load call a function that loads image and once done, this function will return promise. Based on this promise, you can fadeIn div. Unfortunately even I have to learn promise part, but will updated my answer using callbacks

Comment: @Zack I have updated my answer. I also found a post to load async images and have given link of it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.initials {
    position:absolute;
    background:black;
    background-image: url("http://static.tumblr.com/lxn1yld/Hnxnxaqya/space.gif");
    color:white;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:60px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size:17px;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="initials">A</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a little context around your answer. Why is yours different than the answers above? What does it do to the solve the problem? Does it even solve the problem?