# Angular: image won't display once retrieved

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm using angular to make a `http.get` request to retrieve an image I have stored on the backend. Problem is once I get it, I don't know how to display it. Here's my code:

Node:

```
getImage = function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', req.query.mimetype)
    fs.createReadStream(path.join('./uploads/', req.query.filename)).pipe(res)
}
```

Angular

```
$http.get("/getImage/", {params: {"filename" : $scope.recipe.image.filename, "mimetype" : $scope.recipe.image.mimetype}})
.then(function(returnData){
    $scope.image = returnData.data;
})
```

HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{image}}">
```

I've used `console.log` to attempt to display what is coming back, and this is what I get:

[image]

I'm guessing that's the image, but again, I don't know how to properly display it. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you try to do. You should get the `filename-url` of that image rather than using the actual "image" when you use it `<img ng-src="{{image}}">` tag

Comment: But how do I send the parameters back to retrieve the right image then? Because the URL is just `/getImage/`. And if I try to use the path to the image, it just gives me a 404 error.

Comment: Unless you know the actual path to the image, then perhaps the comment made by Daniel Beck is a possible solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your purposes you should use async image upload. So you can use deffered objects:
[Asynchronously load images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/asychronously-load-images-with-jquery)
please look on "phpcoding" answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting byte array from database, use

```
<img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{image}}">
```

Add sanitization filter for data to not be marked as unsafe by angular

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|ftp|blob):|data:image\//);
```