# How do I parse an object in an arrary in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, parsing

```
const params = {
    entity: 'musicTrack',
    term: 'Muzzy New Age',
    limit: 1
};

searchitunes(params).then(console.log);
```

I want `searchitunes(params).then(console.log)` to be a variable instead of being logged.

Comment: What's the definition of your `searchitunes` method?

Comment: const searchitunes = require('searchitunes');
https://www.npmjs.com/package/searchitunes

Comment: Perhaps you want to read about promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access it inside the then handler:

```
 searchitunes(params).then(result => {
   // Use result here
 });
```

Or using async / await:

```
 (async function() {
   const result = await searchitunes(params);
   // Use result here
 })();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this follows the normal [Javascript promises framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), then `console.log` is just a function passed into it like any other. So you can just use your own function where you access the response directly as a variable:

```
searchitunes(params).then(function(response) {
    //Your result is now in the response variable.
});
```

Or if you prefer the newer lambda syntax (the two are identical):

```
searchitunes(params).then(response => {
  //Your result is now in the response variable.
});
```

As per the comment, you can obtain the artwork URL by just traversing the object the same as you would any other object, so:

```
var artworkurl = response.results[0].artworkUrl100;
```

From there you can [use AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) to obtain the contents of that URL, or just [create an img element that points to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/asynchronously-load-images-with-jquery).

Comment: I want to get the album art, here is a response form the api:https://pastebin.com/PTWzqLrN, I want the album art url to be a variable

Comment: It worked but now I'm trying to use them and Its having an issue: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50140444/issue-loading-img-to-html-from-json