# jQuery how to execute function after image loaded on selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute function after image loading finish on selector. How can I achieve this task?

```
    $('#svg_image').show().attr('src', file);
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        $("#svg_image").load(function() {
            resolve({width: $(this).naturalWidth, height: $(this).naturalHeight})
        });
    })
```

Comment: `.load()` as shortcut for load event is deprecated. Where are you returning that promise to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronously load images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/asynchronously-load-images-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onload` event handler, no need for Promise.

The code below loads an image, after load has finished it shows the size, and 2 seconds after that it resizes the image. The delay is just for demo purposes, so you can see the image being resized. Normally you'd use `image.onload = SetDimensions;`.

```js
var image = $("#img")[0];
image.onload = ShowThenSetDimensions;

image.src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0a88079f9234aca9f67c04bf7b94eca4?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1";

function ShowThenSetDimensions() {
  console.log("Size: " + image.naturalWidth + " x " + image.naturalHeight);
  console.log("SetDimensions will be called in 2 seconds");
  window.setTimeout(SetDimensions, 2000);
}

function SetDimensions() {
  image.style.width = image.naturalWidth + "px";
  image.style.height = image.naturalHeight + "px";
  console.log("SetDimensions done");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" style="width:10px; height:10px">
```

Comment: Good answer. I've one incredibly minor thing to note - I had to check your profile and I wasn't surprised to find that you're active in C# - in JS functions usually start with a lowercase letter :P

Comment: Caught me ;-) well at least I put the curly braces where they 'belong' right?

Comment: Heh, I don't think there is a set standard for that in JS :)

Comment: And since using jQuery already can use `$('#img').on('load', function(){ // "this" is the image element})` ...  `$('#img').attr(...).on('load',ShowThenSetDimensions)`

Answer (score -2):

Please try with this code,

```
 $("#svg_image").load().then(function(){
 resolve({width: $(this).naturalWidth, height: $(this).naturalHeight})
});
```

Answer (score -5):

i think you can use setTimeout like :

```
setTimeout(function(){
 // your code
}, 3000); //3 sec
```

so your image loading after 3s

Comment: I want proper solution once image loading finsh then I want to execute function. BTW Thanks for solution.

Comment: Or takes 1/4 second and now won't display for 3 seconds?