# How to ajax request just an image src that changes around every 3 minutes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, src

I just need to request the src attribut image on a website. The source changes around 2 times every 10 minutes, so i can't paste the link's image.
It's been a long time i'm looking for but nothing.

There is my code :

```js
function loadPicture() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://myAdress.com',
            success: function(picture) {
              $('#picture').attr('src', picture); },
            error: function() {
              $('#picture').text('Une erreur est                            survenue.'); },
          });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronously load images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285042/asynchronously-load-images-with-jquery)

Comment: But it's a source that changes around every 3 minutes :/

Answer (score 0):

Set timeout for 3 seconds and load function again and again:

```
function loadPicture() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://myAdress.com',
            success: function(picture) {
              $('#picture').attr('src', picture); },
            error: function() {
              $('#picture').text('Une erreur est                            survenue.'); },
          });
        setTimeout(function(){loadPicture();},180000);//180 seconds
        }
     loadPicture();
```

Comment: I found who to do haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Nice !
I found how to just request the src image.
I had to assign my parameter with .attr('src') to a new variable.

```js
type: 'POST',
url: 'https://myAdress.com',
success: function(picture) {
var myPicture = $(picture).attr('src'); },
```